# SQL: calculate different columns with events and dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have this columns:

- user_id (xxxx)
- order_id (xxxx)
- order_date (2020-07-01)

I would like to have per user_id the following calculated columns:

- ordered at least 1 time or more, between 2020-07-01 to 2020-12-31 (6m)
- ordered at least 3 times or more, between 2020-07-01 to 2020-12-31 (6m)
- ordered at least 1 time or more, between 2020-07-01 to 2020-09-30 (3m)
- ordered at least 1 time or more, between 2020-07-01 to 2020-08-31 (1m)

The result value could be e.g. "ordered" vs "not ordered" to populate the columns.

I'm using redshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the group by and conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select user_id,
       case when
            count(case when order_date between xxxx1 and yyyy1 then 1 end) > 1
            and count(case when order_date between xxxx2 and yyyy2 then 1 end) > 3
            and count(case when order_date between xxxx3 and yyyy3 then 1 end) > 1
            and count(case when order_date between xxxx4 and yyyy4 then 1 end) > 1 
       then 'Yes' else 'No' end as res_
 from your_table -- where ... -- use where condition to restrict the result if required
 group by user_id
```

Replace dates with `xxxxn` and `yyyyn`

Comment: thanks! I edited the counts bc I don't want them actually, I just need a y/n answer whether that happened. And I also added an ELSE to say 'no'. But, I'm getting all the time 'yes', I'm filtering out the ones that didn't comply with the requisite:

Comment: `,case when order_date between '2020-07-01' and '2020-12-31' then 'returned' else 'not returned' end as o1in6m 
    ,case when order_date between '2020-07-01' and '2020-12-31' then 'returned' else 'not returned' end as o3in6m 
    ,case when order_date between '2020-07-01' and '2020-09-30' then 'returned' else 'not returned' end as o1in3m 
    ,case when order_date between '2020-07-01' and '2020-08-31' then 'returned' else 'not returned' end as o1in1m`

Comment: thanks for the update. this got closer! mind I'd need the result for each of the 4 cases, and in your last script it's just giving an overall result. what Im trying right now is this:

Comment: `,case when count(case when order_date between '2020-07-01' and '2020-12-31' then 1 end) >= 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as o1in6m 
    ,case when count(case when order_date between '2020-07-01' and '2020-12-31' then 1 end) >= 3 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as o3in6m
    ,case when count(case when order_date between '2020-07-01' and '2020-12-31' then 1 end) >= 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as o1in3m
    ,case when count(case when order_date between '2020-07-01' and '2020-12-31' then 1 end) >= 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as o1in1m`